# Using NOW() in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, rails-migrations

Is there a way I can create a migration with NOW() + INTERVAL 1

```
class AddFields < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :campaign_groups, :start_at, :datetime, null: false, defaut:->{NOW()}
    add_column :campaign_groups, :end_at, :datetime, null: false, default:->{NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY}
  end
end
```

When I run rake db:migrate, I get a syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting do or '{' or '('
default:->{NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. The `now()` your'e using is a database function that the database interprets, not Ruby code. You want to get the `now()` and `now() + interval '1 day'` into the database so your lambdas need to return strings:

```
default: -> { 'now()' }
default: -> { "now() + interval '1 day'" }
```

PS: You had a typo in `default:` (was `:defaut`) in the `:start_at` options.

AFAIK the `now()` and `now + interval '1 day'` expressions are PostgreSQL-specific. If you're using MySQL then you'd want to use `current_timestamp` and `current_timestamp + interval 1 day`:

```
default: -> { 'current_timestamp' }
default: -> { 'current_timestamp + interval 1 day' }
```

Comment: I got the error: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ interval '1 day' NOT NULL' at line 1: ALTER TABLE `campaign_groups` ADD `end_at` datetime DEFAULT now() + interval '1 day' NOT NULL

Comment: Sorry, didn't know you were using MySQL (thought it was PostgreSQL). I've updated for something that should work with MySQL. The main point is that the lambdas need to return strings.